# Delegating more than 1 event handler

Tags: c#, delegates, mouseevent, eventhandler

I developed the following code:

```
namespace Main___Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            flowLayoutPanel1.AllowDrop = true;
            flowLayoutPanel2.AllowDrop = true;
            flowLayoutPanel3.AllowDrop = true;

            flowLayoutPanel1.DragEnter += panel_DragEnter;
            flowLayoutPanel2.DragEnter += panel_DragEnter;
            flowLayoutPanel3.DragEnter += panel_DragEnter;

            flowLayoutPanel1.DragDrop += panel_DragDrop;
            flowLayoutPanel2.DragDrop += panel_DragDrop;
            flowLayoutPanel3.DragDrop += panel_DragDrop;
        }

        void panel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        void panel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ((GroupBox)e.Data.GetData(typeof(GroupBox))).Parent = (FlowLayoutPanel)sender;
        }

        void createOrder(string orderJSON)
        {
            JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(orderJSON);

            GroupBox order = new GroupBox();
            order.Size = new Size(108, 68);

            Label table = new Label();
            table.Text = "Table: " + jsonObj["table_id"];
            table.Location = new Point(2, 8);
            table.Size = new Size(50, 15);

            Label timestamp = new Label();
            timestamp.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            timestamp.Location = new Point(55, 8);
            timestamp.Size = new Size(50, 15);

            Label orderPrice = new Label();
            float totalPay = 0.0f;
            foreach (var price in jsonObj["Requests"])
            {
                totalPay += (float)price["productTotalPrice"];
            }
            orderPrice.Text = "Total price: " + totalPay.ToString() + " €";
            orderPrice.Location = new Point(2, 50);
            orderPrice.Size = new Size(100, 15);

            order.Controls.Add(table);
            order.Controls.Add(timestamp);
            order.Controls.Add(orderPrice);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(order);

            order.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(delegate (object o, MouseEventArgs a)
            {
                OrderDetails od = new OrderDetails();
                od.ShowDialog();
            });

            order.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(delegate (object o, MouseEventArgs a)
            {
                order.DoDragDrop(order, DragDropEffects.Move);
            });
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Simulate order 1
            Order order = new Order
            {
                table_id = 1,
                Requests = new List<requests>
                {
                    new requests {productName = "Coffee", productQuatity = 3, productTotalPrice = 1.95f},
                    new requests {productName = "Beer", productQuatity = 2, productTotalPrice = 2.20f},
                    new requests {productName = "Water", productQuatity = 1, productTotalPrice = 1f},
                    new requests {productName = "Pretzel", productQuatity = 2, productTotalPrice = 3.25f},
                }
            };

            string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);
            createOrder(JSON);

            //Simulate order 2
            var order2 = new Order
            {
                table_id = 1,
                Requests = new List<requests>
                {
                    new requests {productName = "Coffee", productQuatity = 3, productTotalPrice = 1.95f},
                    new requests {productName = "Pretzel", productQuatity = 2, productTotalPrice = 3.25f},
                }
            };

            string JSON2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order2);
            createOrder(JSON2);
        }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int table_id { get; set; }
        public List<requests> Requests { get; set; }
    }

    public class requests
    {
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public int productQuatity { get; set; }
        public float productTotalPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The behavior I'm getting is:

- Drag'n'drop ✓
- onClick (x)

But if one of the events (doesn't matter which one) is commented, the other one works fine.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

=========================================================================

[SOLUTION]

So I managed to get some ideas here and there, and came up with this:

```
order.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(delegate (object o, MouseEventArgs a)
            {
                var X = Cursor.Position.X;
                var Y = Cursor.Position.Y;

                Thread.Sleep(300);

                if ((Cursor.Position.X > X + 10 || Cursor.Position.X < X - 10) || (Cursor.Position.Y > Y + 10 || Cursor.Position.Y < Y - 10))
                    isDragAndDrop = true;
                else
                    isDragAndDrop = false;


                if ( isDragAndDrop )
                {
                    order.DoDragDrop(order, DragDropEffects.Move);
                }
                else
                {
                    OrderDetails od = new OrderDetails();
                    od.ShowDialog();
                }
            });
```

The var isDragAndDrop is global and a boolean ( checks if withing 300ms the user moved the mouse when pressed on the target. If yes, the variable becomes true, enabling the `DoDragDrop` event).

The `Thread.Sleep(300)` simulates the "long press".

Comment: Curious, why are you serializing then deserializing your order?  You might want to separate the deserialization from the `createOrder` method to make things a bit more extensible.

Comment: You can only ever get a MouseDoubleClick event when the mouse handling goes through its normal cycle.  So Down and Up twice.  But when you also use MouseDown to call DoDragDrop then the show is over, the mouse is now used by the D+D plumbing and no longer delivers the Up notification.  Having a control do both makes for tricky UI, to the user and your code, the only way to make it work is by also using MouseMove to detect that the user moved it far enough while holding down the button.